# How to exclude rows from sum but still show them?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `itemsInShippment` with the following data:

```
itemid shippmentid qty
10         1       100
20         1       200
10         2       300
10         3       1000
```

and table `shippments`

```
shippmentid date         shippmentstatus    supplierid
1           2015-01-12         OK               5000
2           2015-01-17         OK               5000
3           2015-01-17         Cancelled        5000
```

I need to write a query that shows this details about specific shippment say `shipmentid 1`. My given parameters are `supplierid` and `date`. together they related to one shipment (unique).

For `supplierid=5000` and `date=2015-01-12` I want to get:

```
itemid        qty               qtyInOtherShipments
10            100                    300                      //1000 is canceled.
20            200                      0
```

My query works fine without considering the cancelled:

```
SELECT cte.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         a.itemid, b.date, a.qty,
         (coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid), 0) - 
          coalesce( SUM(a.qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid, a.shipmentid)  ,0)  ) AS qtyInOtherShipments,
     FROM
         itemsInShippment a
     LEFT JOIN
         shippments b using (shippmentid)
     WHERE 
         b.supplierid = 5000) AS cte
  WHERE 
      cte.date = '2015-01-12'
```

the `cte` must be this way as in `qtyInOtherShipments` I Sum the total `qty` and then remove my own `qty`. In order to sum the total `qty` I can't do `WHERE d.date=...` inside I must do that outside.

This query gives:

```
itemid        qty               qtyInOtherShipments
10            100                    1300
20            200                    0
```

I'm having trouble taking under consideration the `cancelled` shipments.
if I change the `Where` to :

```
where b.supplierid = 5000 and b.shippmentstatus not like 'cancelled'
```

it works...  I will see:

```
itemid        qty               qtyInOtherShipments
10            100                    300              
20            200                      0
```

but if I run the query on cancelled shipments (`supplierid=5000 and date=2015-01-17`) I will get:

```
itemid        qty               qtyInOtherShipments
nothing
```

what I should have get is:

```
itemid        qty               qtyInOtherShipments
10            1000                      300
```

so my problem is that I don't want to sum `itemid` that is related to cancelled but I still want to see this rows.

How do I get the correct result?

Comment: `like 'canceled'` should be `ilike 'canceled'` I suppose.. and anyway why not  `!= 'Canceled'`?..

Comment: try to put a case statement on your sum. Like, 
case when b.shippmentstatus not like 'Cancelled' then sum(a.qty) else 0 end. Not sure if this will work on your case. Hope it helps. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to exclude canceled items only from sums. So, do not filter them with where, just filter them on sums:

```
SUM(case when b.shippmentstatus <> 'cancelled' then a.qty end) OVER (PARTITION BY ...
```

Sum does not take in consideration null, that's why the above works. (When status is canceled the case expression will return null.)

Comment: You can also use `FILTER` to make it more efficient if on PostgreSQL 9.4; see followup answer.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient variant of Florian's answer exists for PostgreSQL 9.4, the `filter` clause for an aggregate.

```
SUM (a.qty) FILTER (WHERE b.shippmentstatus <> 'cancelled') OVER (PARTITION BY ...
```

See [`FILTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html) in the docs for aggregates. It's basically a mini-`WHERE` clause that applies only for that aggregate.

Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing it out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query

```
create table #itemsInShippment (itemid int, shippmentid int, qty int)

insert into #itemsInShippment (itemid, shippmentid, qty)
SELECT 10 as itemid,   1 as shippmentid,       100 as qty  UNION
SELECT 20  ,   1,       200   UNION
SELECT 10  ,   2,      300   UNION
SELECT 10  ,   3,      1000


CREATE TABLE #shippments (shippmentid int , dt date,  shippmentstatus varchar(50),    supplierid int)

insert into #shippments (shippmentid, dt, shippmentstatus,supplierid)
SELECT 1 as shippmentid,     '2015-01-12' as dt,         'OK' as shippmentstatus    ,           5000 as supplierid UNION ALL
SELECT 2,           '2015-01-17',         'OK'      ,         5000 UNION ALL
SELECt 3,           '2015-01-17' ,        'Cancelled'   ,     5000 




SELECT cte.* 
    FROM (

          select a.itemid,b.dt,a.qty,
                 (coalesce( SUM(case when shippmentstatus <> 'Cancelled' then a.qty else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid)  ,0) - 
                   coalesce( SUM(case when shippmentstatus <> 'Cancelled' then a.qty else 0 end) OVER (PARTITION BY a.itemid,a.shippmentid)  ,0)  )
                   AS qtyInOtherShipments
          from #itemsInShippment a
          left join #shippments b on a.shippmentid = b.shippmentid                                 
          where b.supplierid = 5000  --and shippmentstatus = 'Cancelled'
        ) as cte
  where cte.dt='2015-01-12'
```

Comment: `#itemsInShippment` is an invalid identifier in SQL. It's also shorter/better to use the `values` with an `insert` if you want to insert static values.

Comment: # is used to create temporary table in SQL. I am just used temporary table, so any one can check any database and no need to drop it. However you can use your physical table instead of temporary table.

Comment: The question is tagged `postgresql` and Postgres you create temporary tables with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...`

Comment: indeed i'm using postgresql

Comment: "SQL" is a _query_ language. And in (standard) SQL, `#` is invalid in an identifier and in "SQL" this also won't create a temporary table.